# Limit number of characters inside string containing HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string that looks like the below. I'd like a function in Javascript that would take such a string as a parameter, and number of real characters (ex: 20), and return the final HTML with the limited characters.

```
<div>
<p>This is line 1</p>
<p>This is the second line</p>
</div>
```

So for the above, it should return:

```
<div>
    <p>This is line 1</p>
    <p>This i</p>
</div>
```

I understand this may be too complicated to do, but i basically want to take an HTML string and ultimately render it with a specified limit of characters. If there is any other way that would also be good. Thanks!

Comment: You're only counting text and not the HTML tags themselves?

Comment: this could be easy or quite difficult depending on some assumptions. Is the html input string allowed to have any kind of html content? Or is it always just a parent div containing only a finite set of children div, each one having just text?

Comment: _"I'd like a function"_: SO isn't a code-writing service. You should add the code you've attempted so far to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: You will basically have to recursively iterate over your DOM nodes, and sum up the length of the text nodes they contain. Once you reached your target length, you will need to cut the current text node to size, and then remove all other element nodes that "come after."

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Yes the string can have ANY html content and structure.

Comment: @CBroe yes, thought of this, but thought it's too complicated to write and can get very tricky for certain scenarios. Was wondering if anyone has already done something like this and could provide a solution. Thanks!

Comment: a good solution would be to use DOMParser to parse the html input and then having a recursive function navigating that dom deep until a nodeType==text is found so that any given parent element has an exact content length (it could be used .textContent but it's not the same) and you can track down the exact parent containing the detailed element whose content will be truncated. It will take some time to get there with a good result

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the .substring() Function

```js
const numOfChars = 5 - 1; // Five is the Input you get
const pElem = document.querySelectorAll('p');
pElem[1].innerText = pElem[0].innerText.substring(0,numOfChars);
```

```html
<div>
<p>This is line 1</p>
<p>This is the second line</p>
</div>
```

Be sure to subtract 1 from the amount of desired characters, because the substring Function starts counting at 0